# Mark the difference between 2 pictures in Python

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have recently started to play with Pillow. I am comparing two pictures in Python 3.3 and want to save the difference as an image.

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageChops
from PIL import ImageDraw

file1 = '300.jpg'
file2 = '300.jpg'

im1 = Image.open(file1)
im2 = Image.open(file2)

diff = ImageChops.difference(im1, im2).getbbox()
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im2)
draw.rectangle(diff)
im2.convert('RGB').save('file3.jpg')
```

But I always get a **TypeError: argument must be sequence**

I believe this happens at **draw.rectangle(diff)**
How can I get rid of the error?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you show the full stacktrace so we can see exactly where's the error?

Comment: @AvihooMamka of course:

File "test.py", line 13, in <module>
    draw.rectangle(diff)

  File 

"C:\Users\John.Smithj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageDraw.py", line 192, in rectangle
    
self.draw.draw_rectangle(xy, ink, 0)

TypeError: argument must be sequence

Comment: You can try my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From PIL [documentation](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/ImageDraw.html#PIL.ImageDraw.PIL.ImageDraw.Draw.rectangle):

> `PIL.ImageDraw.Draw.rectangle(xy, fill=None, outline=None)`
>   Draws a rectangle.
>
> Parameters:
>   xy – Four points to define the bounding box.
>
> Sequence of either `[(x0, y0), (x1, y1)]` or `[x0, y0, x1, y1]`. The second point is just outside the drawn rectangle.
>
> outline – Color to use for the outline.
>
> fill – Color to use for the fill.

This means that you should pass a sequence, and from the [documentation](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html?highlight=getbbox#PIL.Image.Image.getbbox) as well:

> `Image.getbbox()`
>
> Calculates the bounding box of the non-zero regions in the image.
>
> Returns:  The bounding box is returned as a 4-tuple defining the left,
>   upper, right, and lower pixel coordinate. If the image is completely
>   empty, this method returns None.

So the problem is that you pass a 4 tuple to a function that expects a sequence of either `[(x0, y0), (x1, y1)]` or `[x0, y0, x1, y1]`

You can wrap your 4 tuple with `list()` literal to get the second option of what the function expects:

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageChops
from PIL import ImageDraw

file1 = '300.jpg'
file2 = '300.jpg'

im1 = Image.open(file1)
im2 = Image.open(file2)

diff = ImageChops.difference(im1, im2).getbbox()
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im2)
diff_list = list(diff) if diff else []
draw.rectangle(diff_list)
im2.convert('RGB').save('file3.jpg')
```

Or if you want to replace the input to the first type `rectangle` expects you can do the following:

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageChops
from PIL import ImageDraw

file1 = '300.jpg'
file2 = '300.jpg'

im1 = Image.open(file1)
im2 = Image.open(file2)

diff = ImageChops.difference(im1, im2).getbbox()
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im2)
diff_list_tuples = >>> [diff[0:2], diff[2:]] if diff else [(None, None), (None, None)]
draw.rectangle(diff_list)
im2.convert('RGB').save('file3.jpg')
```

Comment: @JohnSmith I didn't downvote your question. I up voted it now.

Comment: That code above is not working as per this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63842750/not-getting-right-result-from-python-pillow-diff-operation).  Any idea?