# Not getting right result from Python Pillow diff operation

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am following the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44496249/mark-the-difference-between-2-pictures-in-python) to perform a diff between two images.  Not sure why this line doesn't work in Python 3.  The code fails at the `>>>` operator.

```
diff_list_tuples = >>> [diff[0:2], diff[2:]] if diff else [(None, None), (None, None)]
```

So I follow a modification of the first method:

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageChops
from PIL import ImageDraw

file1 = 'file1.jpg'
file2 = 'file2.jpg'

im1 = Image.open(file1)
im2 = Image.open(file2)

diff = ImageChops.difference(im1, im2)
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im2)
diff_list = list(diff.getbbox()) if diff.getbbox() else []
draw.rectangle(diff_list)
im2.convert('RGB').save('file3.jpg')
```

I dont quite get what is wrong, but it always gives me an exact copy of the second file.  Any clue would be appreciated.

---

Searching around, I stumble across this [post](https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2016/10/11/how-to-create-a-diff-of-an-image-in-python/).  The desired outcome is achieved simply with:

```
if diff.getbbox():
    diff.save('file3.jpg')
```

With that cleared, can someone explains to me what exactly does the failed method try to do, and why it failed?  Just for learning purpose.

Comment: ">>>"  is not a python operator. refer here for python operators https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html

Comment: @APPBird, thanks!  Do you happen to understand what that line of code is or how it is supposed to function?